# Помогите определиться с порядком использования звёздочек в сносках

Tags: пунктуация

В тексте использована сноска в виде * (звёздочки). Проблема в том, что текст состоит из четырёх абзацев, по сути, имеющих сходный текст. Но звёздочка стоит только в первом. С этого момента началось разделение мнений: одни утверждают, что * относится только к первому абзацу (а звёздочка стоит именно там), другие - что ко всем четырём. "Тырнет" ничего не даёт. Множество ссылок на всевозможные ГОСТы, но там тоже ничего. Для простоты приведу пример текста:
- все белки по весне ищут сделанные на зиму запасы и съедают их*;
- все барсуки по весне ищут сделанные на зиму запасы и съедают их;
- все ежи по весне ищут сделанные на зиму запасы и съедают их;
* в дуплах.
Пример слишком очевиден, ежи в дуплах не живут, но содержание исходного текста не такое конкретное, я привёл в пример только структуру.
Кто ещё не забыл правила, помогите разобраться! Если ещё и источник-основание укажете - буду безмерно благодарен! Верните веру в Родной язык!)

Answer (score 1):

Если звёздочка стоит только в первом абзаце, то только к нему и относится сноска. Если дальше идут похожие фрагменты, их объяснять уже не требуется: объяснили в первом. Если бы нужны были ещё какие-то комментарии, они были бы обозначены двумя, тремя звёздочками.

> Надстрочная звёздочка (АСТЕРИСК)  —  классический знак сноски или
>   примечания (в старину её иногда даже относили к знакам препинания и
>   называли «примечательный знак»). Второе, третье и т. д. примечания
>   обозначаются в отечественной типографской традиции двумя, тремя и т.
>   д. звёздочками в ряд. (Если количество сносок превышает 3, то вместо
>   звёздочек рекомендуется использовать цифры на верхнюю линию).

http://wiki-linki.ru/Citates/763573

Эти же сведения и здесь:

> Подстрочные примечания помещаются внизу той страницы, на которой
>   расположены требующие пояснения фрагменты (текст, таблица, график,
>   рисунок). Подстрочные примечания связаны с основным текстом знаком
>   сноски – «звездочкой» или арабской цифрой. Если на странице не более
>   трех примечаний, можете обозначить их соответственно *, ** и ***.
>   Однако более наглядным является использование арабских цифр,
>   написанных на верхней границе строки.

https://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-103068-kak-oformit-primechanie

Если это ссылка на источник, то внизу под знаком одной звёздочки пишут полные выходные данные источника со страницей, а если следующий абзац из этого же источника, то ставят две звёздочки и пишут "Там же, стр.   ..."

У Вас одна звёздочка - указание на примечание **к тому абзацу, в конце которого она стоит.**